# Unable To Execute restore Operation

Tags: sql-server, restore

I tried to run this SQL statement:

```
RESTORE DATABASE test1 
FROM DISK = N'D:\Projects\Billing DB\Test1.bak' 
WITH REPLACE;
```

but all I get are these errors:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test1.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> File 'ChickenDB' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test1.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test1.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> File 'ChickenDB_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test1.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Does the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` exist on the host?

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says you need to use WITH MOVE to specify valid file locations for the database files.  By default the file locations on the source system are used.

An easy way to do this is to restore the database with the [restore wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-database-general-page?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(sql13.swb.restoredb.general.f1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver16) in SSMS.  It will write the SQL for you, and even execute it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Server backup file contains information on where the database files were located when the (full) backup (set) was created.

In your case the backup file contains the following information:

```
 Logical Name  | Physical Name
---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ChickenDB     | C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test1.mdf
 ChickenDB_log | C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test1.ldf
```

When restoring a database with the [`RESTORE DATABASE ....`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command, then the restore process will read the backup file and extract this information and use it as a default value for the restore process.

If you want to determine the file locations stored in the backup file then use the [`RESTORE FILIELISTONLY...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command.

> Returns a result set containing a list of the database and log files contained in the backup set in SQL Server.

You can use the [`RESTORE FILIELISTONLY...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command like this:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = `D:\Projects\Billing DB\Test1.bak`;
```

In order to restore the database to a new location you will have to use the `MOVE` parameter of the [`RESTORE DATABASE ....`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command.

> MOVE 'logical_file_name_in_backup' TO 'operating_system_file_name' [ ...n ]
>
> Specifies that the data or log file whose logical name is specified by logical_file_name_in_backup should be moved by restoring it to the location specified by operating_system_file_name. The logical file name of a data or log file in a backup set matches its logical name in the database when the backup set was created.

#### Solution

For your backup you would probably be best of with something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE test1 
FROM DISK = N'D:\Projects\Billing DB\Test1.bak' 
WITH 
    MOVE 'ChickenDB' TO 'D:\SomeDirectory\Test1.mdf',
    MOVE 'ChickenDB_log' TO 'D:\SomeDirectory\Test1.ldf',
    REPLACE, 
    RECOVERY;
```

Example code can also be found in the online documentation for the [`RESTORE DATABASE ....`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command in the example [D. Restore a database and move files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#restoring_db_n_move_files).